# Call Action delegate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core

In .NET Core Logging [LoggerMessage.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerMessage.cs)

method `Define<T1>(...)` is defined like:

```
public static Action<ILogger, T1, Exception> Define<T1>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string formatString)
{
    var formatter = CreateLogValuesFormatter(formatString, expectedNamedParameterCount: 1);

    void Log(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, new LogValues<T1>(formatter, arg1), exception, LogValues<T1>.Callback);
    }

    return (logger, arg1, exception) =>
    {
        if (logger.IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            Log(logger, arg1, exception);
        }
    };
}
```

Can anybody explain me what is the benefit of creating local function `Log(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, Exception exception)` ?

and what is the difference if method `Define<T1>(...)` would be defined without the local `Log` function, like this:

```
public static Action<ILogger, T1, Exception> Define<T1>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string formatString)
{
    var formatter = CreateLogValuesFormatter(formatString, expectedNamedParameterCount: 1);

    return (logger, arg1, exception) =>
    {
        if (logger.IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, new LogValues<T1>(formatter, arg1), exception, LogValues<T1>.Callback);
        }
    };
}
```

Are there any performance reasons?

Comment: If compare delegate and local function, the local has benefit for performance. But in this case, it seems there is not so much benefit of it. In my guess, the code has been changed from `static` to local function. It has also benefit because the compiler can merge down the functions to one.